# проблемы с select html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть такой пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectId").change(function() {        
        $("#text").text($("#selectId option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Количество записей на странице:</p>
<select id="selectId">   
    <option value="1">15</option>
    <option value="2">25</option>
    <option value="3">50</option>
    <option value="3">100</option>
</select>

<p>Количество записей: <span id="text">15</span></p>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при выборе одно пункта в select перегружалась страница с сохранением выбраного значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const getUrlParam = function (name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results === null) {
            return null;
        }
        return results[1] || 0;
    };

    $('#selectId').on('change', () => {
        let value = $(this).val();

        window.location.href = `www.example.com?param=${value}`;
    })

    window.onload = () => {
        const newVal = getUrlParam('param');

        $('#selectId').val(newVal);
    }
```